# g++ can't find -ludev, but libudev.so is there

Tags: 20.04, compiling, make, g++

I'm getting an error I can't understand.

I'm playing with a new package that runs some hardware over a USB port.

So I try to compile one of their simple example programs:

```
$ make example1
mkdir -p ./x86_64
g++ -I./../../include -std=c++17 -g -O0  -c -fmessage-length=0 -o ./x86_64/example1.o ../../example1/example1.cpp
g++ -o ./x86_64/example1.run ./x86_64/example1.o -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/lib -ldl -lpthread -lrt -ludev
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ludev
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:23: example1] Error 1
```

And yet:

```
$ file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev*
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1:      symbolic link to libudev.so.1.6.17
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.17: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=f160d354074c8338225478996d8b005386ba795b, stripped
```

Sign me confused...

Answer (score 3):

`libudev.so.1` is there (as a symbolic link to `libudev.so.1.6.17`), but for the *additional* symlink to `libudev.so` required by the build-time linker `ld` you will need to install the `libudev-dev` package:

```
$ dpkg -S libudev.so
libudev1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.7.0
libudev-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so
libudev1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1
```

Comment: So, as currently installed, programs which were linked against libudev  are happy with libudev.so.1, but in order to link a new program, we need a libudev.so which is a link pointing to libudev.so.1?

Comment: @dawfedora that's pretty much it, yes

Comment: `apt-get install libudev-dev` reports that it "is already the newest version (249.11-0ubuntu3.6)". (ubuntu 22.04) Would it make sense to create the symlink manually?

Comment: Oh, funny. `apt-get install --reinstall libudev-dev`  created the symlinks for me